# What do $\cup$ and $\cap$ mean here? (set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $D_i := \{x \in \Bbb R: (-i \le x \le i)\} = [-i,i]$.

What does the notation for (i) mean?

$$(i)~ \bigcup_{i=1}^4 D_i, \quad(ii)~ \bigcap_{i=1}^4 D_i, \quad(iii)~ \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i$$

Comment: Union of the sets $D_i$ where $i$ iterates from $1$ to $4$. Analogously for the others. In other words  
$(i)$ is the same as $D_1\cup D_2\cup D_3\cup D_4$

Comment: thanks alvin, that's what I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\bigcup_{i=1}^4 D_i = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3 \cup D_4$.

This is analogous to $\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4$, e.g.

$\bigcap_{i=1}^4 D_i = D_1 \cap D_2 \cap D_3 \cap D_4$, and the last one goes to $n$ (which is fixed for the sum), the $i$ is the running index that takes values $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I will accept your answer in a few mins (have to wait 10mins..)